# В switch есть диапазон значений?

Tags: c#

Что-то такое:

```
switch (val)
{
     case -1...1:
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147879/switch-case-can-i-use-a-range-instead-of-a-one-number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Диапазон написать нельзя, но можно его сымитировать таким образом, указав несколько case для одного блока:

```
switch (number)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
        //...
        break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        //...
        break;
}
```

Возможно в C#7 появилась возможность записи диапазонов, но у меня нет возможности проверить.

Answer (score -1):

Используй алтернативу switch -- ifElse

Или сделай как примере :

```
int mynumbercheck = 1000;

var myswitch = new Dictionary <Func<int,bool>, Action>
{ 
         { x => x < 10 ,    () => //Do this!...  },  
         { x => x < 100 ,    () => //Do this!...  },
         { x => x < 1000 ,    () => //Do this!...  },
         { x => x < 10000 ,   () => //Do this!... } ,
         { x => x < 100000 ,  () => //Do this!... },
         { x => x < 1000000 ,  () => //Do this!... }
};
```

Вызов

```
myswitch.First(sw => sw.Key(mynumbercheck)).Value();
```

Comment: Dictionary не гарантирует хранение и перечисление значений в том порядке, в котором они были в него добавлены. Т.е. поведение кода из вашего примера неопределено. Если хочется предсказуемого поведения - стоит использовать `List<KeyValuePair<Func<int, bool>, Action>>` / `List<Tuple<Func<int, bool>, Action>>`

Comment: Чем это лучше чем серия `if - else if`?